# function in opencv that can give the minimum value of a 2d or 3d matrix along a specific dimension

Tags: opencv, max, min

Is there a function in opencv, which can compute the minimum value of a 2d or 3d matrix along a specific dimension. And give me the index of the minimum value.

Minimizing in 1 dimension would mean, if I have a 3d matrix the result should be a 2d matrix, and if I have a 2d matrix than the result should be a 1d matrix(array) of indices where the min/max value is stored.

minMaxIdx and MinMaxLoc gives the global minimum index/value along all the dimensions.

Answer (score 4):

cv::reduce will give you row or column wise minimum or maximum. But I don't think it will give you the index. A "find()" function is what lacks in OpenCV.

Comment: There is min/max function in armadillo but that returns only the index of the global minimum [link](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#min_and_max_member). what I want is something similar to min/max function provided in matlab.

Comment: I guess the easiest way is too loop through each row/col (whichever dimension u want to search) and use cv::minMaxIdx or cv::minMaxLoc on each row/col plus the iterator value to work out their global index?